# PostgreSQL always returns success for delete operations (sqlc related)

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlc

Since PostgreSQL always returns success for delete operations (sqlc related), how can I write the PostgreSQL syntax that can be read by sqlc to check the rows affected after execute delete operations, so that the method generated by sqlc will return (int, err) instead of err only?

Comment: For temporary solution I can only think of first to use sqlc to generate a function that getItemById then if there is no error, I can safely call the function to delete the selected item with given id.

Comment: I don't know what code sqlc generates, but normal Go execution of a delete query, done using the Exec method, will return an sql.Result which provides the number of affected rows (iff the driver implements that feature). Another way to get the number is to use the `RETURNING` clause with delete, scan the result of that into a slice and the check the length of that slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:execrows` query annotation to return the number of affected rows from the result returned by `ExecContext`.

see https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/v1.12.0/reference/query-annotations.html

e.g.

given the table...

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
  id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  bio        text   NOT NULL
);
```

You can annotate the query with `:execrows` like so...

```
-- name: DeleteAuthor :execrows
DELETE FROM authors WHERE id = $1;
```

Which should give code generated like so - notice return is `(int64, error)` - not just `error`...

```
package db

import (
    "context"
)

const deleteAuthor = `-- name: DeleteAuthor :execrows
DELETE FROM authors WHERE id = $1
`

func (q *Queries) DeleteAuthor(ctx context.Context, id int32) (int64, error) {
    result, err := q.db.ExecContext(ctx, deleteAuthor, id)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return result.RowsAffected()
}
​
```

I made a working playground for this here
https://play.sqlc.dev/p/2d7791f88a5e2414eb18b6b6b07846dd61df00a03007df869ff3821cb1b12dcd